# When switch user with su - <someuser>, a line from the .bash_profile is printed to console

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

A particular line in my ~/.bash_profile gets printed to console when I su - .
Below is the output demonstrating this scenario.

```
$ whoami
admin
$ su - spark
Password: 
Last login: Fri Mar  6 21:30:22 +08 2020 on pts/2
[1]+  Done                    export JDBC=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.100.117/test?user=spark
$
```

I dont understand why the line `export JDBC=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.100.117/test?user=spark` gets printed to console. That line is a line in my ~/.bash_profile of user spark.

I have checked `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/sh.local` but nothing out of ordinary found. Also added `set echo off` to `~/.bash_profile` but the line still gets printed when `su -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in `.bash_profile` of `spark` user you may have line like:

```
export JDBC=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.100.117/test?user=spark &
```

and this ampersand (`&`) on the end cause this command to be executed as background job.

Or you have something like in `.bash_profile`:

```
export JDBC=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.100.117/test?user=spark&parameter=something
```

and again ampersand (`&`) cause this. You can change the line to be

```
export JDBC='jdbc:postgresql://192.168.100.117/test?user=spark&parameter=something'
```

to avoid it

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, I can sleep tonight.